# From list of dict to single dict using values as key/value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

From a JSON input, I have a list of dictionaries, all using the same keys:

```json
[{'id': '1', 'country': 'Brazil'},
 {'id': '2', 'country': 'Spain'},
 {'id': '3', 'country': 'South Korea'},
 {'id': '4', 'country': 'United States'},
 {'id': '5', 'country': 'Italy'}]
```

Since I need an easy way to get the `id` value from any `country` name, I want to convert this into a single dictionary:

```py
{'Brazil': 1, 'Spain': 2, 'South Korea': 3, 'United States': 4, 'Italy': 5}
```

I thought I could do this with a dictionary comprehension:

```py
countries = {k:v for d in my_list for (k, v) in d.values()}
```

However, this yields:

```py
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Which I didn't expect, since `d.values()` should only return two items.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you're thinking about [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), not `dict.values`.

Comment: What is `d` in your `dict` comprehension? I thought you had a `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `dict.items` yield a tuple.

However, just changing `values` with `items` will overwrite your freshly generated dictionary (and furthermore, not leading to your desired result).

```py
>>> {k:v for item in my_list for (k,v) in item.items()}
{'id': '5', 'country': 'Italy'}
```

Instead, you have to specify the keys you need.

```py
>>> {item['country']:item['id'] for item in my_list}
{'Brazil': '1', 'Spain': '2', 'South Korea': '3', 'United States': '4', 'Italy': '5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values as a tuple and reverse it. then you can pass them to the dict call to create your new dict.

```py
my_list = [{'id': '1', 'country': 'Brazil'},
 {'id': '2', 'country': 'Spain'},
 {'id': '3', 'country': 'South Korea'},
 {'id': '4', 'country': 'United States'},
 {'id': '5', 'country': 'Italy'}]


countries = dict(tuple(d.values())[::-1] for d in my_list)
print(countries)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'Brazil': '1', 'Spain': '2', 'South Korea': '3', 'United States': '4', 'Italy': '5'}
```